# How to stop guessing game after correct input in Python?

Tags: python, loops, random, while-loop, python-3.6

I tried to make a guessing game for my tutorial, and it doesn't stop asking inputs even after correct number guessed.
can anyone help?

''' #asking user to guess the hidden number in 5 attempts

```
import random
hidden = random.randint(1,20)
win = False
attempt = 0
total_attempt = 5

while attempt < total_attempt:
     while win == False:
          guess = int(input('Guess the Number:'))
          attempt += 1

          if hidden == guess:
             print ('You got it in', attempt, 'Guesses')
             win == True
             break
          else:
               if hidden > guess:
                   print ('Your guess is too low')
               else:
                   print ('Your guess is too high')
               break
print ('Not guessed,The correct answer was', hidden)
```

'''

Comment: `win == True` doens't update the value of the win variable. I think you meant to write `win = True`

Answer (score 1):

Your `break` only breaks the inner `while` loop, not the outer one.  While you could do tricky stuff with a flag that allows the inner loop to signal the need for a break to the outer loop, the simplest fix is to use only a single loop, and use conditional `break`s that allow you to stop it for different reasons:

```
import random
hidden = random.randint(1,20)
attempt = 0
total_attempt = 5

while True:
    guess = int(input('Guess the Number:'))
    attempt += 1
    if hidden == guess:
        print ('You got it in', attempt, 'Guesses')
        break
    if attempt >= total_attempt:
        print ('Not guessed,The correct answer was', hidden)
        break
    if hidden > guess:
        print ('Your guess is too low')
    else:
        print ('Your guess is too high')
```

Another option might be to use a `for` loop over the range of `attempt`s, with a `break` to end it early for a win and an `else` to indicate the loss when the loop is exhausted:

```
import random
hidden = random.randint(1,20)

for attempt in range(5):
    guess = int(input('Guess the Number:'))
    if hidden > guess:
        print('Your guess is too low')
    elif hidden < guess:
        print('Your guess is too high')
    else:
        print('You got it in', attempt + 1, 'guesses')
        break  # ends the loop and skips its "else"
else:
    print('Not guessed,The correct answer was', hidden)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm new to coding and I hope I'll be better.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is quite easy to find & correct in your code. On line 12, you have the following command : `win == True`. However, the operator `==` doesn't change the value of the variable, it's only used to verify and equality and return a boolean. What you want in your code is to ***change*** the value of the boolean variable `win`, not just verify it. Therefore, your code would need to look like this :

```
import random
hidden = random.randint(1,20)
win = False
attempt = 0
total_attempt = 5

while attempt < total_attempt:
     while win == False:
          guess = int(input('Guess the Number:'))
          attempt += 1

          if hidden == guess:
             print ('You got it in', attempt, 'Guesses')
             win = True
             exit(0)
          else:
               if hidden > guess:
                   print ('Your guess is too low')
               else:
                   print ('Your guess is too high')
               break
print ('Not guessed,The correct answer was', hidden)
```

Please not that I added the `exit(0)` command in case the user finds out the correct number, which will just make the Python script stop.